# The do I make http / https requests over serial? (pyserial)

Tags: python, serial-port

I was wondering how to make HTTP requests (No headers just url) over serial via a middleman

COM Only PC <--> COM and Networked PC <--> Internet

and I wrote two pieces of code to test it but it doesn't work can someone please help

This is middle man

```
import serial
import requests

# Open the serial port for reading and writing
ser = serial.Serial('COM5', baudrate=9600, timeout=1)

while True:
 # Read a message from the serial port
 message = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').strip()
 # If the message is a URL, download the page or file at the URL
 if message.startswith('http'):
  response = requests.get(message)
  data = response.content
  # Send the file back through the serial port
  ser.write(data)
```

This is the COM only

```
import serial

# Open the serial port for reading and writing
ser = serial.Serial('COM6', baudrate=9600, timeout=1)

# Prompt the user to enter a URL
url = input('Enter a URL: ')

# Send the URL over the serial port
ser.write(url.encode())

# Wait for the response from the server
response = ser.read_all()

# Save the response to a file
with open('response.bin', 'wb') as f:
 f.write(response)
```

It should go like this:

The server would await a message via the COM port that starts with "HTTP"

The client once entered a URL will send the URL to the server

The server once received the URL will make a request to the URL

Once the download is complete send the content response back over the COM port

After the client has received the content save's it to response.bin

Comment: You're using inconsistent names. First you mention "*COM Only PC*" and "*COM and Networked PC*". Then it's "*middle man*" and "*COM only*". Then suddenly it's just "*server *" and "*client*". You need to clearly explain your setup, and use consistent names  and descriptions.   "*It doesn't work*" is not an adequate description of the results and problem. What have you done to debug this issue? Anything at all? Have you tried to break the grand scheme into smaller phases or steps?

Comment: What specific issue do you have and what code have you already tried?